# Issue Keeping PHP Login Data After jQuery DIV Refresh

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax

Ok so I store my session in PHP and MySQL and the login works properly throughout the entire site.

I'm trying to add a feature where a specific div gets refreshed using jQuery set to refresh every 10 seconds.  I've gotten the code to work properly when calling information from the database without any issues.

The issue that I am running into is the information that gets grabbed for the certain page requires that the user be logged in to the website, so if a certain variable is set then it brings the user to the group page after checking to make sure that the user is associated with that group within the database.

Apparently the jQuery refresh is not passing through that the user is logged in so it just asks the user to be logged in instead of displaying the groups data.

Here are some screen shots that show the issue that I am getting.

This is a screenshot of what should be showing up with my group section:
[image]

This is my test screen that contains my jQuery DIV refresh and changes the text after 10 seconds:
[image]

But unfortunately when the area refreshes it shows up like this as though the user is not logged in:
[image]

Now on to the code, just don't judge me on my poor codemanship :) - This is my test.php?groupid=1:

```
include('core/header.php');
if (isset($_SESSION['user_id'])) {
    $user_id = $_SESSION['user_id'];
    $username = $user -> username;
}
?>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Update Text Area Content in a Div Tag</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="screen"><h1>Ok look here...I'm going to change text in 10 seconds.</h1></div>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script>
        $(document).ready(function(){
        setInterval(function(){
        $("#screen").load('data.php' + location.search);
        }, 10000);
        });
        </script>
</body>
</html>

<?php include('core/footer.php'); ?>
```

Here is my data.php script:

```
<?php
if (session_status() == PHP_SESSION_NONE) {
    session_start();
}

    // connect to database
    $connect = mysqli_connect("localhost", "*****", "*****", "*****");

    if (!$connect) {
        die("Error connecting to database: " . mysqli_connect_error());
    }

if (isset($_SESSION['user_id'])) {
    $user_id = $_SESSION['user_id'];
    $username = $user -> username;
}

if(isset($_GET['groupid'])) {
    $id = $_GET['groupid'];
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM alliances_coalitions WHERE id = '$id'";
    $result = mysqli_query($connect, $sql);
    // fetch all posts as an associative array called $posts
    $group = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC);

}
?>
     <!--********************************************* Main start *********************************************-->
     <div id="main_news_wrapper">

       <div id="row"> 
       <!-- Left wrapper Start -->
        <div id="left_wrapper">
            <div class="header">
            <h2><span>ACADEMY //</span> <?php echo $group['title']; ?></h2>
            </div>
            <?php 
            if (isset($_GET['message'])) {
                if ($_GET['message'] == "success") {
                    echo '<h3>Your request was successfully sent, please wait for the admin to reply</h3>';
                }

                if ($_GET['message'] == "exists") {
                    echo '<h3>You have already sent in your request, please wait for the admin to reply</h3>';
                }
            }

            if (!isset($user_id)) {
                echo '<a href="login.php" class="read_more2">Login To join '.$group['title'].'</a>';
            } else if (isset($user_id)) {
                //lookup user and see if they are a part of the group
                $groupid = $group['id'];


                $sql = "SELECT * FROM `team_members` WHERE `team_id` LIKE '" .$groupid. "' AND `member_id` LIKE '" .$user_id. "'";
                $results = mysqli_query($connect, $sql);
                if (mysqli_num_rows($results) == 0) {
                    echo '<a href="request_group_entry.php?team='.$groupid.'&user='.$user_id.'" class="read_more2">Request To Join Team</a>';
                } else {

                }
            } else {

            }
            ?>
            <img style="position:relative;left:25%;width:50%;height:auto;" src="<?php echo $group['logo']; ?>">
            <p style="padding:10px;"><?php echo $group['description']; ?></p>
            <?php 
            if (isset($user)) {
                $sql = "SELECT * FROM `team_members` WHERE `team_id` = '" .$groupid. "' AND `member_id` = '" .$user_id. "'";
                $results = mysqli_query($connect, $sql);
                if (mysqli_num_rows($results) == 0) {

                } else {
                    $row = mysqli_fetch_array($results, MYSQLI_ASSOC);
                    extract($row);
                ?>
            <div class="iframecontainer" id="body">
                <iframe style="position:relative;left:10px;" class="iframe" src="<?php  if ($group['titan_link'] != ""){echo $group['titan_link'];} ?>" frameborder="0"></iframe>
            </div>
            <?php } ?>

            <ul id="general_news">
                <?php
                // Get team info and see if user is a part of the group.
                if (mysqli_num_rows($results) == 0) {

                } else {
                    if ($member_rank == "admin") {
                ?>
                <?php 
                if (!isset($_GET['createpost'])) { ?>
                    <a href="?groupid=<?php echo $groupid; ?>&user=<?php echo $user_id; ?>&createpost=true" class="read_more2">Create New Post</a><br/>
                <?php } else if (isset($_GET['createpost'])) { ?>
                <!--THIS IS THE CKEDITOR-->
                <form id="form" action="addblogpost.php?groupid=<?php echo $groupid; ?>&user=<?php echo $user_id; ?>" method="POST">
                    <div style="position:;top:250px;">
                    <input type="hidden" id="user_id" name="user_id" value="<?php echo $user_id; ?>">
                    <input type="hidden" id="username" name="username" value="<?php echo $user -> username; ?>">
                    <!--<label for="blogavatar_file">Upload Blog Avatar Image</label>-->
                    <!--    <input type="file" id="blogavatar_file" name="blogavatar_file" accept=".jpg, .jpeg, .png">-->
                    <label for="blogavatar_url">Blog Category</label>
                    <input style="padding-right:10px;" type="text" id="category" name="category" placeholder="strategy, target, goal, news, etc."><br/><br/>
                    <label for="blogavatar_url">Title</label>
                    <input style="padding-right:10px;" type="text" id="title" name="title"><br/><br/>
                    <label for="blogavatar_url">Blog Avatar URL</label>
                    <input style="padding-right:10px;" type="url" id="blogavatar_url" name="blogavatar_url"><br/><br/>
                    </div>
                    <div style="position:absolute;">
                    <label style="position:relative;left:300px;top:-225px;" for="short_text">Short Text</label>
                    <textarea style="position:relative;left:300px;top:-225px;resize:none;" id="short_text" name="short_text" rows="10"></textarea><br/><br/>
                    </div>
                    <textarea id="textarea" name="textarea" rows="10"></textarea>
            <script>
                // Replace the <textarea id="editor1"> with a CKEditor
                // instance, using default configuration.

        CKEDITOR.replace( 'textarea', {
    filebrowserBrowseUrl: '/ckfinder/ckfinder.html',
    filebrowserImageBrowseUrl: '/ckfinder/ckfinder.html?type=Images',
    filebrowserFlashBrowseUrl: '/ckfinder/ckfinder.html?type=Flash',
    filebrowserUploadUrl: '/ckfinder/core/connector/php/connector.php?command=QuickUpload&type=Files',
    filebrowserImageUploadUrl: '/ckfinder/core/connector/php/connector.php?command=QuickUpload&type=Images',
    filebrowserFlashUploadUrl: '/ckfinder/core/connector/php/connector.php?command=QuickUpload&type=Flash'
});
            </script>
            <br/>
            <div class="form_submit"><input type="submit" value="Create Blog Post" class="read_more2" /></div>
        </form><br/>
            <?php
                    }}
            $posts = getAllianceNews();
            foreach ($posts as $post): ?>
            <li>
              <div class="image"><a href="#"><img alt="alt_example" src="<?php if ($post['image'] === "") {echo 'images/post/data.jpg';} else {echo $post['image'];} ?>" /></a></div>
              <!--<ul class="social_share">
                <li><a href="#"><img alt="alt_example" src="images/fbk.png" border="0" /></a></li>
                <li><a href="#"><img alt="alt_example" src="images/twitter.png" border="0" /></a></li>
                <li><a href="#"><img alt="alt_example" src="images/more.png" border="0" /></a></li>
              </ul>-->
              <div class="info">
                <div class="comments"> <?php echo $post['comments']; ?> </div>
                <?php if (isset($post['topic']['name'])): ?>
                        <a class="read_more"
                            href="<?php echo 'filtered_posts.php?topic=' . $post['topic']['id'] ?>"
                            class="btn category">
                            <?php echo $post['topic']['name'] ?>
                        </a>
                    <?php endif ?>
                <h2><a href="#"><?php echo $post['title']; ?></a></h2>
                <div class="date_n_author"><?php echo $post['created_at']; ?>, by <?php echo $post['username']; ?></div>
                <p><?php echo $post['short_body']; ?></p>
                <a href="#" class="read_more2">Read More</a> </div>
                <div class="clear">
              </div>
            </li>
            <?php endforeach ?>
            <?php }}?>
          </ul>
          <!--<ul id="pager">
            <li><a href="#" ><img alt="alt_example" src="images/left_pager.jpg" border="0"/></a></li>
            <li><a href="#" >1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">2</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" class="active">3</a></li>
            <li><a href="#"><img alt="alt_example" src="images/right_pager.jpg" border="0"/></a></li>
          </ul>-->


          <div class="clear"></div>
          </div>
        <!-- Left wrapper end --> 

        <!-- Right wrapper Start -->
        <div  id="right_wrapper">
         <!--   <div id="search">-->
         <!--     <input type="text" onblur="if(this.value =='') this.value='search'" onfocus="if (this.value == 'search') this.value=''" value="search" name="s" class="required" id="s" />-->
         <!--     <input type="button" />-->
         <!--   </div>-->
         <!--<div class="categories">-->
         <!--   <div class="header"><a href="#">Categories</a></div>-->
         <!--   <ul>-->
         <!--     <li> <a href="#">Beginners Guides</a> </li>-->
         <!--     <li> <a href="#">Advanced Guides</a> </li>-->
         <!--     <li> <a href="#">Combat Strategy</a> </li>-->
         <!--     <li> <a href="#">Station Builds</a></a> </li>-->
         <!--     <li> <a href="#">Spying Techniques</a> </li>-->
         <!--   </ul>-->
         <!-- </div>-->
          <?php if (isset($user)) {
              $sql = "SELECT * FROM `team_members` WHERE `team_id` LIKE '" .$groupid. "' AND `member_id` LIKE '" .$user_id. "'";
                $results = mysqli_query($connect, $sql);
          // Get team info and see if user is a part of the group.
                if (mysqli_num_rows($results) == 0) {

                } else {
          ?>
          <table>
              <tr>
                  <td style="vertical-align:top;">
                      <?php
                        if ($member_rank == "admin") {
                         ?>
                             <div style="width:170px;" class="categories">
                                <div style="width:150px;" class="header"><a href="#">Admin Panel</a></div>
                                <ul style="width:150px;">
                                  <li > <a style="width:150px;" href="?groupid=<?php echo $groupid; ?>&page=manage_members">Manage Members</a> </li>
                                </ul style="width:150px;">
                              </div>
                        <?php
                        }
                        ?>
                      <div style="width:170px;" class="categories">
                        <div style="width:150px;" class="header"><a href="#">Alliance Info</a></div>
                        <ul style="width:150px;">
                          <li > <a style="width:150px;" href="#">Main Page</a> </li>
                          <li > <a style="width:150px;" href="#">Targets</a> </li>
                          <li > <a style="width:150px;" href="#">Spy Reports</a> </li>
                          <li > <a style="width:150px;" href="#">Battle Reports</a> </li>
                          <li > <a style="width:150px;" href="#">Military</a></a> </li>
                          <li > <a style="width:150px;" href="#">Black Ops</a> </li>
                          <li > <a style="width:150px;" href="#">Engineers</a> </li>
                        </ul style="width:150px;">
                        </div>
                        <div style="width:170px;" class="categories">
                        <div style="width:150px;" class="header"><a href="#">Tools</a></div>
                        <ul style="width:150px;">
                          <li > <a style="width:150px;" href="#">Combat Calculator</a> </li>
                          <li > <a style="width:150px;" href="#">Spy Report Parser</a> </li>
                          <li > <a style="width:150px;" href="#">Station Planner</a> </li>
                        </ul style="width:150px;">
                      </div>
                  </td>
                  <td style="vertical-align:top;">
         <div style="position:relative;top:-10px;text-align:center;">
                      <h2>Members</h2>
                     <?php
                     echo '<h3>Admin</h3>';
                     echo '<a href="profile.php?user='.$username.'&userid='.$user_id.'"><img style="position:relative;right:25px;" class="avatar" src="'.$avatar.'" width="30px"><div style="position:relative;left:20px;bottom:24px;">'.$username.'</div></a>'; 
                     echo '<h3>Military</h3>';
                     echo '<a href="profile.php?user='.$username.'&userid='.$user_id.'"><img style="position:relative;right:25px;" class="avatar" src="'.$avatar.'" width="30px"><div style="position:relative;left:20px;bottom:24px;">'.$username.'</div></a>'; 
                     echo '<a href="profile.php?user='.$username.'&userid='.$user_id.'"><img style="position:relative;right:25px;" class="avatar" src="'.$avatar.'" width="30px"><div style="position:relative;left:20px;bottom:24px;">'.$username.'</div></a>';
                     echo '<a href="profile.php?user='.$username.'&userid='.$user_id.'"><img style="position:relative;right:25px;" class="avatar" src="'.$avatar.'" width="30px"><div style="position:relative;left:20px;bottom:24px;">'.$username.'</div></a>';
                     echo '<a href="profile.php?user='.$username.'&userid='.$user_id.'"><img style="position:relative;right:25px;" class="avatar" src="'.$avatar.'" width="30px"><div style="position:relative;left:20px;bottom:24px;">'.$username.'</div></a>';
                     echo '<a href="profile.php?user='.$username.'&userid='.$user_id.'"><img style="position:relative;right:25px;" class="avatar" src="'.$avatar.'" width="30px"><div style="position:relative;left:20px;bottom:24px;">'.$username.'</div></a>';
                     echo '<h3>Black Ops</h3>';
                     echo '<a href="profile.php?user='.$username.'&userid='.$user_id.'"><img style="position:relative;right:25px;" class="avatar" src="'.$avatar.'" width="30px"><div style="position:relative;left:20px;bottom:24px;">'.$username.'</div></a>'; 
                     echo '<a href="profile.php?user='.$username.'&userid='.$user_id.'"><img style="position:relative;right:25px;" class="avatar" src="'.$avatar.'" width="30px"><div style="position:relative;left:20px;bottom:24px;">'.$username.'</div></a>';
                     echo '<a href="profile.php?user='.$username.'&userid='.$user_id.'"><img style="position:relative;right:25px;" class="avatar" src="'.$avatar.'" width="30px"><div style="position:relative;left:20px;bottom:24px;">'.$username.'</div></a>';
                     echo '<a href="profile.php?user='.$username.'&userid='.$user_id.'"><img style="position:relative;right:25px;" class="avatar" src="'.$avatar.'" width="30px"><div style="position:relative;left:20px;bottom:24px;">'.$username.'</div></a>';
                     echo '<a href="profile.php?user='.$username.'&userid='.$user_id.'"><img style="position:relative;right:25px;" class="avatar" src="'.$avatar.'" width="30px"><div style="position:relative;left:20px;bottom:24px;">'.$username.'</div></a>';
                     echo '<h3>Engineers</h3>';
                     echo '<a href="profile.php?user='.$username.'&userid='.$user_id.'"><img style="position:relative;right:25px;" class="avatar" src="'.$avatar.'" width="30px"><div style="position:relative;left:20px;bottom:24px;">'.$username.'</div></a>'; 
                     echo '<a href="profile.php?user='.$username.'&userid='.$user_id.'"><img style="position:relative;right:25px;" class="avatar" src="'.$avatar.'" width="30px"><div style="position:relative;left:20px;bottom:24px;">'.$username.'</div></a>';
                     echo '<a href="profile.php?user='.$username.'&userid='.$user_id.'"><img style="position:relative;right:25px;" class="avatar" src="'.$avatar.'" width="30px"><div style="position:relative;left:20px;bottom:24px;">'.$username.'</div></a>';
                     echo '<a href="profile.php?user='.$username.'&userid='.$user_id.'"><img style="position:relative;right:25px;" class="avatar" src="'.$avatar.'" width="30px"><div style="position:relative;left:20px;bottom:24px;">'.$username.'</div></a>';
                     echo '<a href="profile.php?user='.$username.'&userid='.$user_id.'"><img style="position:relative;right:25px;" class="avatar" src="'.$avatar.'" width="30px"><div style="position:relative;left:20px;bottom:24px;">'.$username.'</div></a>';
                     echo '<a href="profile.php?user='.$username.'&userid='.$user_id.'"><img style="position:relative;right:25px;" class="avatar" src="'.$avatar.'" width="30px"><div style="position:relative;left:20px;bottom:24px;">'.$username.'</div></a>'; 
                     echo '<a href="profile.php?user='.$username.'&userid='.$user_id.'"><img style="position:relative;right:25px;" class="avatar" src="'.$avatar.'" width="30px"><div style="position:relative;left:20px;bottom:24px;">'.$username.'</div></a>';
                     echo '<a href="profile.php?user='.$username.'&userid='.$user_id.'"><img style="position:relative;right:25px;" class="avatar" src="'.$avatar.'" width="30px"><div style="position:relative;left:20px;bottom:24px;">'.$username.'</div></a>';
                     echo '<a href="profile.php?user='.$username.'&userid='.$user_id.'"><img style="position:relative;right:25px;" class="avatar" src="'.$avatar.'" width="30px"><div style="position:relative;left:20px;bottom:24px;">'.$username.'</div></a>';
                     echo '<a href="profile.php?user='.$username.'&userid='.$user_id.'"><img style="position:relative;right:25px;" class="avatar" src="'.$avatar.'" width="30px"><div style="position:relative;left:20px;bottom:24px;">'.$username.'</div></a>';
                     echo '<a href="profile.php?user='.$username.'&userid='.$user_id.'"><img style="position:relative;right:25px;" class="avatar" src="'.$avatar.'" width="30px"><div style="position:relative;left:20px;bottom:24px;">'.$username.'</div></a>'; 
                     echo '<a href="profile.php?user='.$username.'&userid='.$user_id.'"><img style="position:relative;right:25px;" class="avatar" src="'.$avatar.'" width="30px"><div style="position:relative;left:20px;bottom:24px;">'.$username.'</div></a>';
                     echo '<a href="profile.php?user='.$username.'&userid='.$user_id.'"><img style="position:relative;right:25px;" class="avatar" src="'.$avatar.'" width="30px"><div style="position:relative;left:20px;bottom:24px;">'.$username.'</div></a>';
                     echo '<a href="profile.php?user='.$username.'&userid='.$user_id.'"><img style="position:relative;right:25px;" class="avatar" src="'.$avatar.'" width="30px"><div style="position:relative;left:20px;bottom:24px;">'.$username.'</div></a>';

                     ?>
                     </div>
                     </td>
                     </tr>
          </table>
          <?php }} ?>

             <!-- Right wrapper end -->

        </div>
        <div class="clear"></div>

        </div>
      </div>

    <div class="bottom_shadow"></div>

    <!--********************************************* Main end *********************************************--
```

Comment: **WARNING**: When using `mysqli` you should be using [parameterized queries](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and [`bind_param`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) to add any data to your query. **DO NOT** use string interpolation or concatenation to accomplish this because you have created a severe [SQL injection bug](http://bobby-tables.com/). **NEVER** put `$_POST`, `$_GET` or data *of any kind* directly into a query, it can be very harmful if someone seeks to exploit your mistake.

Comment: Note: The [object-oriented interface to `mysqli`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.connections.php) is significantly less verbose, making code easier to read and audit, and is not easily confused with the obsolete `mysql_query` interface where missing a single `i` can cause trouble. Example: `$db = new mysqli(…)` and `$db->prepare("…")` The procedural interface is largely an artifact from the PHP 4 era when `mysqli` API was introduced and should not be used in new code.

Comment: **WARNING**: Writing an access control layer is not easy and there are many opportunities to get it severely wrong. Any modern [development framework](https://www.cloudways.com/blog/best-php-frameworks/) like [Laravel](http://laravel.com/) comes with an [authentication system](https://laravel.com/docs/master/authentication) built-in, and there are [authentication libraries](http://phprbac.net/) you can use. At the absolute least follow [recommended security best practices](http://www.phptherightway.com/#security) and **never store passwords as plain-text** or a weak hash like **SHA1 or MD5**.

Comment: You should take down those screenshots immediately. You've just posted code that's **wide open** to anyone looking to take advantage of those SQL injection holes, and finding that site based on screenshots is likely not hard if this is a public site.